# Material disappears after using quick explode?

Tags: materials, modifiers

When I place an image texture on an object it works fine, the material shows up and looks good. I then go and place a quick explode effect on the same object and my material goes away. Can someone help we with this?

**Before**

[image: Before Quick Explode]

--

**After**

[image: After Quick Explode]

Comment: I don't experience that neither in Blender Internal nor in Cycles (you might also want to provide info about your render engine). Can you elaborate on that by adding some screenshots and [uploading your file](http://blender.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: i have added to images one before the quick explode and one after.

Comment: So the image are not in chronological order right? The first image is the one after applying quick explode?

Comment: the one that looks like a stone block is before the quick explode. the grey block is after.

Comment: Did you change something in **Explode** modifier's settings ? The only way I can think of to reproduce that is by changing UV maps used by material and particles.

Comment: I don't remember changing anything. I have completely removed blender from my PC and reinstalled. I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've found there's a difference between Quick Explode and the Explode Modifier.  Quick Explode seems to remove materials, perhaps a bug (I'm on Blender 2.76).  Instead of using Quick Explode, just apply the Explode Modifier to your object instead.  You should find that your materials remain.